# Java Boolean Method with a try/catch and Query inside.. How to combine and returns the appropriate boolean value?

Tags: java, try-catch

/*hi just want to know .. how to make this authenticate boolean method..return the appropriate boolean value. which is embedded by database Queries  **/ 
/*original code is..**/

```
public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {

                      if (username.equals(s1) && password.equals(s2)) 
                 {
                 System.out.println("Logged in");
                 return  true;
                 }
                      return false;
}
```

/*Modified**//*edited**/
Login.java

```
public class Login {

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
     static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
     static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";

     //  Database credentials
     static final String USER = "root";
     static final String PASS = "1234";

    // connection cn = new connection();
     ResultSet rs=null;
     Statement stmt = null;
     static  Connection con = null;
     PreparedStatement pst = null;



    public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {   

      boolean result = false;

try{ 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);     

Statement st=con.createStatement();
String Query="select * from user where username='"+username+"' and password='"+password+"'";

ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(Query);

if(rs.next()) 
{
System.out.println("Successfully passed here!! Just Notifying!!");
result = true;                       
}
}catch(Exception e)
{                       
System.out.println(e);

}
return result;
    }
}
```

/*Another Class**/
LoginDialog.java

```
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (Login.authenticate(getUsername(), getPassword())) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginDialog.this,
                            "Hi " + getUsername() + "! You have successfully logged in.",
                            "Login",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    succeeded = true;
                    dispose();
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(LoginDialog.this,
                            "Invalid username or password",
                            "Login",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    // reset username and password
                    tfUsername.setText("");
                    pfPassword.setText("");
                    succeeded = false;

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Imagine for a moment that you have 5 millions of users in your database. Is it more efficient to ask the database "Find me a user having this name and this password" or to ask it "Find me all the users. Then I'll check every one to see if their name and password match with the ones sent"? If the former, why are you doing the latter?

Comment: because I want my _main form_ to know if the user has successfully logged in by using this _.isSucceeded()_ referenced method..

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
boolean autheticate=false;
                      if (username.equals(s1) && password.equals(s2)) 
                 {
                 System.out.println("Logged in");
                 autheticate=true;
                 }
                      return autheticate;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Biswajit, I've already than that action but still it returns the false value.. I've modified it by using a database connection _see above Modified Login.java_..where I hope it would compare the user input to the db query.. ^_^

Comment: System.out.println(username.equals(s1) && password.equals(s2)) before if statement

Comment: solved it.. Thank you.. lesson learned Do not directly conclude.. sign of a noob..grr. ^_^ @Abhishek thank you for the query stmt..

Answer (score 0):

instead of going through the huge resultset you obtain by doing a select *, use a where clause in the query itself. If the resultset is valid, return true, else return false. This will save execution time. 
You may modify the code as :

String Query="select * from user where username="+username_string+" and password="+password_string+";";

ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(Query);

```
            if(rs.next()) 
                {
                     System.out.println("Logged in");
                        return  true;                       
                }

                       return false;
```

Comment: thanks. just dont know what logic step must be done here.. thats why I tagged _sql_ in this post..  **** <br/>   if I enclose the query with try/catch.. <br/>the states this error .. <br/>_This method must return a result of type boolean_ ^_^